# Finding realtime reliable and precise peak detection algorithm for noisy signals

Tags: c++, algorithm, signal-processing

I am working on one project right now, basically I need to precisely realtime measure peaks measured by Hall sensor through RPi Pico, coding in Arduino IDE through Arduino-Pico library, the problem is, the signal is quite noisy and not every peak is perfect, many are quite destroyed, I need to have reliable and precise algorithm for that. I would be very grateful if someone have worked on similar problem and would be able to give me some advice. The signal looks like this:

This is raw signal from Hall sensor:
[image: This is raw signal from Hall sensor]

This is averaged signal from 4 previous values (data is not the same as previous one):
[image: This is averaged signal from 4 previous values]

I have tried two methods: one was to set a `highThreshold` and, when the value is over it, the program starts to look for the highest number in current region; this worked, although not in parts where the data is somewhat corrupted and the graph does not have proper peak (the curVal is input).

```
  HighThresCoeff = 0.85
  //code for highThreshold generation
  vals[i]=curVal;
  i++;
  if(i==arrSize){
    low=getLow(vals);
    high=getHigh(vals);
    highThreshold=((high-low)*HighThresCoeff+low);
    i=0;
  }
  //peak detection
  if (curVal > highThreshold) {
    activated = true;
    if(curVal > lastHigh){
      lastHigh = curVal;
      lastHighTime = micros();
    }
  } else if (activated == true) {
    lastHigh = 0;
    activated = false;
    t2 = t1;
    t1 = lastHighTime;
    // code for processing the time of the peak
  }
```

The other method I tried was also based on `highThreshold`, although I was looking for time, when the graph value was over and under the threshold, then made an average; this was better although, because of noise, I still haven't had as nice data as I wished for.

```
  HighThresCoeff = 0.85
  //code for highThreshold generation
  vals[i]=curVal;
  i++;
  if(i==arrSize){
    low=getLow(vals);
    high=getHigh(vals);
    highThreshold=((high-low)*HighThresCoeff+low);
    i=0;
  }
  //peak detection
  if (curVal > highThreshold) {
    tss = micros();
    activated = true;
  } else if (activated == true) {
    activated = false;
    tse = micros();
    t2 = t1;
    t1 = tss + ((tse - tss) / 2);
    //code for processing the time further
  }
```

### Additional info:

- Latency:
  If the latency is under 1/3 of peak-to-peak time, and is
  predictable, or constant, it's okay.
- Example data:
  https://github.com/Atores1/exampleData

Comment: I would denoise the signal using median filtering or using total variation denoising with a second order regularization term, solved with majorize-minimize.

Comment: Maybe start by running the samples through a low pass filter. The first thought is to convert each sample such that `lowpass[i] = std::accumulate(vals+i-4, vals +i+4, 0.0)/9`. Then do an easy scan on lowpass to find the periodic peaks.

Comment: At my shop, we pass the signals through a filter, then check for an average peak value.  The signals are from the real world, so thing is going to be precise; thus the need for median values and filterings.

Comment: Your signal looks relatively stable, correlation with a known or averaged signal with a known peak might work.

Comment: Please post the raw data values either to your question or to GitHub so people can play with your raw data and try to come up with their own solutions tested against your actual data. Capture at least a few periods of data. There are a bajillion ways to try to solve this.

Comment: What is the hall sensor measuring? Does it matter if there is a time lag in detecting the peak? Low pass filters add time lag, especially the lower their cutoff frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having noticed the OP provided a link to raw, int data, I ran it through a moving average filter. Advantage of a moving average filter is one doesn't need to add all the samples in the buffer but just subtract the one dropping off and add in the new sample to an initial sum of buffer contents. Far less computational work and memory accesses.

Here's the filtered result overlayed with the original data:

And here's the code that reads in the original data as well as outputs synced original data and filtered data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

using std::array, std::vector, std::size_t;

using sample_type = int;            // data sample type, either int or double
constexpr int Global_Filter_N = 41; // filter length, must be odd

// moving average filter
template <typename T=sample_type, int N=Global_Filter_N>
class Filter_MA
{
public:
    T clk(T in)
    {
        sum += in - buf[index];
        buf[index] = in;
        index = (index + 1) % N;
        if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
            return sum / N;
        else
            return (sum + (N / 2)) / N;
    }
    bool update_vectors(const vector<T>& vin, vector<T>* pvout, vector<T>* prawout = nullptr)
    {
        if (vin.size() <= N || pvout == nullptr)
            return false;
        pvout->reserve(vin.size() - N);
        if (prawout != nullptr)
            pvout->reserve(vin.size() - N);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
            clk(vin[i]);
        for (size_t i = N; i < vin.size(); i++)
        {
            pvout->push_back(clk(vin[i]));
            if (prawout != nullptr)
                prawout->push_back(vin[i - N / 2]);
        }
        return true;
    }
private:
    array<T, N> buf{};  // moving average buffer
    T sum{};            // running sum of buffer
    size_t index{};     // current loc remove output, add input 
};

template <typename T=sample_type>
std::pair<T, T> peak_detect(T y1, T y2, T y3)
{
    // scale pk location by 100 to work with int arith
    T pk = 100* (y1 - y3) / (2 * (y1 - 2 * y2 + y3));
    T mag =  2 * y2 - y1 - y3;
    return std::pair{ pk, mag };
}

struct WaveInfo {
    sample_type w_mean{};
    sample_type w_max{};
    sample_type w_min{};
    vector<sample_type> peaks;
    vector<sample_type> mags;
};

inline WaveInfo get_wave_info(std::vector<sample_type> v)
{
    constexpr int N = Global_Filter_N;
    static_assert(Global_Filter_N & 1, "filter must be odd number");
    WaveInfo w;
    w.w_max = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    w.w_min = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    // "0ll + sample_type{}" Produces either a double or long long int depending on sample_type to stop overflow if > 2M samples
    w.w_mean = static_cast<sample_type>(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0ll + sample_type{}) / std::size(v));
    sample_type pos_thresh = w.w_mean + (w.w_max - w.w_mean) / 10;  // 10% above ave.
    sample_type neg_thresh = w.w_mean + (w.w_min - w.w_mean) / 10;  // 10% below ave
    int search_polarity = 0;    // if 0 prior peak polarity not determined
    for (int i = 0; i < int(v.size()) - N; i++)
    {
        const int center = N/2;
        if (v[i] > pos_thresh && v[i] > v[i + N - 1] && v[i] < v[i + center] && search_polarity >= 0)
        {
            search_polarity = -1;
            auto results = peak_detect(v[i], v[i + center], v[i + N - 1]);
            w.peaks.push_back(results.first * center / 100 + i + center);
            w.mags.push_back(results.second);
        }
        if (v[i] < neg_thresh && v[i] < v[i + N - 1] && v[i] > v[i + center] && search_polarity <= 0)
        {
            search_polarity = 1;
            auto results = peak_detect(v[i], v[i + N / 2], v[i + N - 1]);
            w.peaks.push_back(results.first * center / 100 + i + center);
            w.mags.push_back(-results.second);
        }
    }
    return w;
}

// Used to get text file int samples
vector<sample_type> get_raw_data()
{
    std::ifstream in("raw_data.txt");
    vector<sample_type> v;
    int x;
    while(in >> x)
        v.push_back(x);
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    Filter_MA filter;
    vector<sample_type> vn = get_raw_data();
    vector<sample_type> vfiltered;
    vector<sample_type> vraw;
    if (!filter.update_vectors(vn, &vfiltered, &vraw))
        return 1;   // exit if update failed

    // file with aligned raw and filtered data
    std::ofstream out("waves.txt");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vfiltered.size(); i++)
        out << vraw[i] << " " << vfiltered[i] << '\n';

    // get filtered file metrics
    WaveInfo info = get_wave_info(vfiltered);
    out.close();

    //  file with peak locs and magnitudes
    out.open("peaks.txt");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < info.peaks.size(); i++)
        out << info.peaks[i] << " " << info.mags[i] << '\n';
}
```

Here's the peak info output for the first 4 peaks. First column is location, second column is a relative magnitude of the peak,

```
116 43
344 32
577 44
812 37
```

[image: Filtered data with original data]

Comment: Without studying your code, I'd just like to comment it would be nice to see a plot of your output data and the detected peaks as well. That would help reveal its utility and effectiveness almost instantly in a single glance.

Comment: @GabrielStaples The filter is essentially a 2 tap (.5,.5) FIR repeated N times. Ideal filter would be a matched filter but this repeating 2 tap is remarkably good. Easy to adjust and uses no trig functions so can be easily adapted to cheapo embedded s/w with int only arith.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, it took me some time to test it, how it works, to test it, I had to quite optimize it for my application, but in the end it worked quite well with one of the peak detection methods I mentioned. Although your idea brought me to using analog low pass filter, if that works, it would be ideal. Thank you for your answer! I'll try to test even the new one you posted.

Comment: @Atores Absolutely an analog filter would work. The freqs associated with the noise are very high freq and likely aliasing as past Nyquist. Would greatly reduce filtering computation/complexity.